# showing milliseconds in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using matplotlib to plot data as a function of time in hh:mm:ss.ms format where ms is milliseconds. However, I don't see the milliseconds in the plot. Is it possible to add them as well?

```
dates = matplotlib.dates.datestr2num(x_values) # convert string dates to numbers
plt.plot_date(dates, y_values)  # doesn't show milliseconds
```

Comment: hey there, please post some code that shows what you're doing. That way its a bit easier to help, cheers.

Comment: You might need to add in some qualifier to define the number of decimal places displayed, for example, %.2f.  However, without seeing more of your code, it's hard to know.

Comment: could you, please, post an example? thanks

Comment: What version of python/matplotlib are you using? With Python 2.7 and matplotlib 1.1, I can't find the function "matplotlib.dates.date2strnum"

Answer (score 21, accepted):

---

The problem here is that there is a class to format ticks, and plot_date sets that class to something that you don't want: an automatic formatter that never plots milliseconds.

In order to change this, you need to change from `matplotlib.dates.AutoDateFormatter` to your own formatter. `matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter(fmt)` creates a formatter with a `datetime.strftime` format string. I'm not sure how to get this to show milliseconds, but it will show microseconds, which I hope will work for you; it's just one extra zero, after all. Try this code:

```
dates = matplotlib.dates.datestr2num(x_values) # convert string dates to numbers
plt.plot_date(dates, y_values)  # doesn't show milliseconds by default.

# This changes the formatter.
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter("%H:%M:%S.%f"))

# Redraw the plot.
plt.draw()
```

Answer (score 3):

FWIW, I had this problem and made a workaround which I import from a util module of my package. Microseconds was too much precision, just seconds too little - now I can choose the degree of precision I need (default milliseconds):

```py
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker


class PrecisionDateFormatter(ticker.Formatter):
    """
    Extend the `matplotlib.ticker.Formatter` class to allow for millisecond
    precision when formatting a tick (in days since the epoch) with a
    `~datetime.datetime.strftime` format string.

    """

    def __init__(self, fmt, precision=3, tz=None):
        """
        Parameters
        ----------
        fmt : str
            `~datetime.datetime.strftime` format string.
        """
        from matplotlib.dates import num2date
        if tz is None:
            from matplotlib.dates import _get_rc_timezone
            tz = _get_rc_timezone()
        self.num2date = num2date
        self.fmt = fmt
        self.tz = tz
        self.precision = precision

    def __call__(self, x, pos=0):
        if x == 0:
            raise ValueError("DateFormatter found a value of x=0, which is "
                             "an illegal date; this usually occurs because "
                             "you have not informed the axis that it is "
                             "plotting dates, e.g., with ax.xaxis_date()")

        dt = self.num2date(x, self.tz)
        ms = dt.strftime("%f")[:self.precision]

        return dt.strftime(self.fmt).format(ms=ms)

    def set_tzinfo(self, tz):
        self.tz = tz
```

Thus used as:

```py
from my_util import PrecisionDateFormatter

ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(PrecisionDateFormatter("%H:%M:%S.{ms}"))
```

It might be possible to just monkey patch the `__call__` method of `DateFormatter` once imported rather than copying all of the fluff (and having to do the local imports), but I tried, failed, and decided this was good enough for me!