# How to plot binned datetimes from pd.cut

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

SO I have data like this:

```
LFrame  Date_Time   DoW run_time    az  el  distance    pass_ID SV_ID   Direction   PFD_Jy
0   3114360965  2023-03-29 17:25:20 Wednesday   62720.0 349.254117  12.199639   2.171043e+06    2023_03_29_154  154 SB  8.505332
1   3114360977  2023-03-29 17:25:21 Wednesday   62721.0 349.216316  12.294878   2.164688e+06    2023_03_29_154  154 SB  1085.548185
2   3114360988  2023-03-29 17:25:22 Wednesday   62722.0 349.178240  12.390492   2.158335e+06    2023_03_29_154  154 SB  515.828602
3   3114360999  2023-03-29 17:25:23 Wednesday   62723.0 349.139888  12.486484   2.151987e+06    2023_03_29_154  154 SB  344.120530
4   3114361010  2023-03-29 17:25:24 Wednesday   62724.0 349.101256  12.582857   2.145641e+06    2023_03_29_154  154 SB  37.207705
```

...

I bin it up since it's at 1 sec and I don't want to plot it that densely:

```
binned = SV_pfd_data.groupby(pd.cut(SV_pfd_data.Date_Time, SV_pfd_data.shape[0]//5), as_index=True).mean() # ~1 min bins
binned = binned.reset_index()
```

which results in this data:

```
Date_Time   LFrame  run_time    az  el  distance    SV_ID   PFD_Jy
0   (2023-03-29 17:25:19.408999936, 2023-03-29 17:...   3.114361e+09    62722.5 349.158693  12.438994   2.155165e+06    154.0   448.731927
1   (2023-03-29 17:25:25.008474624, 2023-03-29 17:...   3.114361e+09    62728.0 348.943580  12.972617   2.120295e+06    154.0   213.259464
2   (2023-03-29 17:25:30.016949248, 2023-03-29 17:...   3.114361e+09    62733.0 348.740192  13.468287   2.088688e+06    154.0   556.595627
3   (2023-03-29 17:25:35.025423616, 2023-03-29 17:...   3.114361e+09    62738.0 348.529055  13.974280   2.057173e+06    154.0   872.418091
```

*NOTE THAT THE BINNED DATE/TIME has resolution better than microseconds* Not sure why

However, when I plot:

```
timeOnly = matdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,5))
ax.plot_date(binned.Date_Time, binned.PFD_Jy,
       label=r"$\nu$=1611.1")
ax.set_ylabel("PFD [Jy]")
ax.set_xlabel("Date-time")
ax.set_xticklabels(SV_pfd_data.Date_Time, rotation = 65, fontsize=10)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(timeOnly)
```

I get an error:

```
OverflowError: int too big to convert
```

Comment: Maybe the error comes from trying to plot microseconds. Related [stackoverflow: showing-milliseconds-in-matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11107748/showing-milliseconds-in-matplotlib).

Comment: I gave that a try but it doesn't work with the binned pandas series... I get a `TypeError: Parser must be a string or character stream, not Interval`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
binned = SV_pfd_data.groupby(pd.cut(SV_pfd_data.Date_Time, SV_pfd_data.shape[0]//5), as_index=True).mean() # ~1 min bins
```

Don't cut because it returns interval as bin, instead use [`pd.Grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) to groupby time interval:

```
binned = SV_pfd_data.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date_Time', freq='5T')).mean()
```

**Note** you don't need to reset index of `binned` to plot, and `plot_date` is deprecated:

```
timeOnly = matdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,5))

# pass ax to pandas plot
binned.plot(label=r"$\nu$=1611.1", ax=ax)
ax.set_ylabel("PFD [Jy]")
ax.set_xlabel("Date-time")

# why ticks as original series when your data is grouped?
# ax.set_xticklabels(SV_pfd_data.Date_Time, rotation = 65, fontsize=10)

ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(timeOnly)
```

Comment: Can you specify something like a dict to handle data series that are non-numeric and for which I don't want the 'mean' -- maybe just the first item repeated?

Comment: `groupby().first()`

Comment: I really meant that some series need to be mean, while other need to be 'first' in the same df.

Comment: `df.gropuby('a').agg({'b': 'mean', 'c':'first'})`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the binned Date_Time column back to a datetime object

```py
binned = SV_pfd_data.groupby(pd.cut(SV_pfd_data.Date_Time, SV_pfd_data.shape[0]//5), as_index=True).mean()

binned['Date_Time'] = pd.to_datetime(binned['Date_Time'])

timeOnly = matdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S')
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,5))
ax.plot_date(binned.Date_Time, binned.PFD_Jy, label=r"$\nu$=1611.1")
ax.set_ylabel("PFD [Jy]")
ax.set_xlabel('Date-time')
ax.set_xticklabels(binned.Date_Time.dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S'), rotation=65, fontsize=10)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(timeOnly)
plt.show()
```

Comment: When I try I get an error... 
TypeError: <class 'pandas._libs.interval.Interval'> is not convertible to datetime

Comment: binned.Date_Time looks like:


0    (2023-03-29 17:25:19.408999936, 2023-03-29 17:...
1    (2023-03-29 17:25:25.008474624, 2023-03-29 17:...
2    (2023-03-29 17:25:30.016949248, 2023-03-29 17:...
3    (2023-03-29 17:25:35.025423616, 2023-03-29 17:...
4    (2023-03-29 17:25:40.033898240, 2023-03-29 17:...